# Problems with terminating connection after running scripts on remote computer using shell script

Tags: shell, expect

This is the first time I am writing a shell script. I tried to do as much research as I can to avoid dumb/repetitive question. Please excuse if its repeat/dumb question.

I have a shell script which connects to remote linux machine and runs scripts there. I am using 'expect' to spawn a ssh connection and to issue commands to trigger the job. However, I am having issues while closing the connection after completing the job.

This is my script:

```
set prompt "(%|#|\\$|%\]) $"


    expect -c 'spawn ssh $UN@$STAGE ;
                    expect password ; send "$PASS \n";
                    expect -regexp "$PROMPT"; send "./settings.$UN.sh > settings_log.txt \n";
                    interact'
```

This script successfully runs the script file for me ($UN and $STAGE parameters are input to the script. I omitted that here for simplicity). However,  this leaves me with an open connection.
I tried to close the connection after running the script by using following instead of above

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh   $UN@$STAGE ;
                expect password ; send "$PASS \n";
                expect -regexp "$PROMPT"; send "./settings.$UN.sh > settings_log.txt \n";
                expect -regexp "$PROMPT"; send "exit \n"'
```

This does close the connection but I noticed that my script file did not run at all. Also the settings_log.txt is not generated at all.

Does this mean, that exit command is aborting the process before its completion? I tried using 'sleep' before exit but it did not help. Is there a better suggested way to terminate the connection when using expect?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain to me what *expect -regexp "$PROMPT"* does? I'm not familiar with *expect*.

Comment: This is the first time with expect.

expect -regexp "$PROMPT" waits for the shell to complete its work, which and return for user input. For example
I start a ssh connection using .

expect -c 'spawn ssh   $UN@$STAGE ;

Now,I know that ssh will ask for password.Since I know this upfront,I can tell my script to be prepared for it and send the password when this occurs.This is achieved by following statement.

expect password ; send "$PASS \n"

You can also give regular expression to expect.That is what I tried to do.I defined a variable ($PROMPT) at the top and used it in next statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with expect, you terminate your send commands with `\r` not `\n`, so

```
 expect -c 'spawn ssh   $UN@$STAGE
            expect password
            send "$PASS\r"
            expect -regexp "$PROMPT"
            send "./settings.$UN.sh > settings_log.txt\r"
            expect -regexp "$PROMPT"
            send "exit\r"
            expect eof'
```

Answer (score 1):

Note you can execute remote shell commands and copy files using *ssh* and *scp*, directly, without using *expect*.

For example,

```
scp ./settings.$UN.sh $UN@$STAGE:settings_log.txt
ssh $UN@$STAGE whatever-you-need-to-execute
```

The connection will close as soon as soon as *whatever-you-need-to-execute* completes.

Comment: I tried doing this. But ssh $UN@$STAGE asks me for a password. I need this script to work without user intervention. Say, if I can create HTML form for user where he enters his UN and PWD, I want my system to fire this script. I cannot do it ssh prompts me for PWD. So, I am using except.

Comment: You can either identify yourself with a certificate, use *expect* to provide the password to *ssh*, or use *sshpass* to do it for you. Note the first option is by far the most secure, and also works for *scp* (as does the second, but which is less secure).

Comment: Ok great. That sounds like a better way to do it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your outer script seems to be written in csh and sets a variable named "prompt", but your `expect` script is using a variable called "PROMPT". Try making the two variable names match case.

Comment: the case mismatch was a typo by me. in my actual scrip both are in same case